# Checking for string value in the server hostname

Tags: bash, sed, sh, cut, rhel

I have RHEL servers which have hostname in the format as
`la45serapp090.lba.com`

I want to return true if `hostname` has string `serapp`

I have written the following command so far but it is just returning value `45`

`uname -n | cut -c3,4`

Comment: What do you mean by "return true"?  Are your writing a function?  Functions and scripts can only return an integer between 0-255.  Or do you mean to set a variable to `True` or maybe to echo the text value `"true"`?

Answer (score 4):

You can do a pattern match in `if`:

```
if [[ `uname -a` == *serapp* ]];
then echo serapp server
else echo non-serapp server
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

with a regex:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $( uname -a ) =~ serapp ]]; then
    return 0
else
    return 1
fi
```